# WebKit for C# 2015

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, webkit, chromium

I Wanted to know is there any WebKit port for C# (.NET). As far as I found there is only this [WebKit.Net](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) port which was first hosted on Sourceforge and then moved on to [Github](https://github.com/webkitdotnet). But the problem is it was last updated 2 years ago in 2013 which is now old. So is there any other port of WebKit for C# which is in active development ? If not, how can I my self port WebKit for C# ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a library that called [CEFsharp](http://cefsharp.github.io/). It is a library that is based on [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef), the open source version of [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/), and can be used to embed a full-featured standards-complaint web browser into your C# or VB.NET app.

Answer (score -3):

You can take a look at [DotNetBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser).
This project is developed actively, there is usually about one release per month. It provides a Chromium-based component that can be embedded in a .NET application.

DotNetBrowser itself is commercial, but there are free open-source and academic licences.

Actually,  I work with the team, which created it ;)

Comment: Can I use it in my software which is free non-commercialized closed-source licensed?

Comment: We provide free licences for open source projects, or academic projects, for which we grant temporary free licences. Other types of licences are commercial.

Comment: You need to request a license for your project, including a link to the project repository.  This prohibits the vast majority of projects, since any project that would actually need the library won't exist without access to the library to begin with....